# school project: upload/download a file to localhost by python through http requests (the uploaded files are viewable)

Tags: python, browser, download, upload, client-server

I need to implement a project to upload/download file from/to localhost, by Python, from the command line. But the uploaded files need to be viewable from the browser.

Basically i know i need to have a client, a server, and an endpoint(http://localhost).
(1)upload:
From the client side(command line), i send the file through python request package by http requests. The server side will receive this file and parse this file to get the information in the file. I need to see the uploaded file from the browser.
(2)download:
from the command line of the client side, i ask for the file through http request. Then the request will be parsed by server. Then the file will be saved locally to my host machine.
(3)i know how to use the Python request package.

Question: what do i need to work on the server side and client side?
I read through the similar posts for this question, and they are not helpful for my question.

Comment: Please clarify a few things (please edit your question accordingly): 1. Are you supposed to write the client software AND the server software? Or only one of them (which). 2. Only if you have to write the server software as well: Is the server software supposed to run directly on the machine (i.e. are you supposed to implement the HTTP) or does it run as some kind of CGI script (or similar) like in apache? 3. What kind of files is it that you should upload/download?

Comment: A totally valid but probably as useless answer would be "you need a computer and a python interpreter installed on it". So ... 4. What exactly is it you need help with?

Comment: @ Bodo Thiesen Thanks for your help. I need to write both the server side and client side, plus the front-end.